# Storage of Split Mirror Backup in DB2

Tags: split, db2, backup, storage, mirror

Can someone tell me about the storage requirement, i.e. whether a Tape is required for storing the Split Mirror Backup in DB2?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, split mirror does not require any additional storage.

Originally you have a mirrored pair of disk volumes, each storing an exact copy of the same data. After you split the mirror, you still have the same pair of disk volumes, only now they are not synchronised, and the volume that was split off contains an image of the database at the time of the split.

Comment: And if we take the split backup with standby option, the database will be in rollforward  pending state until we take it out of that state, so this could help in keeping both the copies in sync. I hope my understanding is correct!!